# How do I convert a string of bits to a hex string in Python?

Tags: python, string, binary, hex

I have a bit-string of 32 characters that I need to represent as hexadecimal in Python. For example, the string `"10000011101000011010100010010111"` needs to also be output as `"83A1A897"`.

Any suggestions on how to best go about this in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python conversion from binary string to hexadecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072351/python-conversion-from-binary-string-to-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 24):

To format to hexadecimal you can use the hex function:

```
>>> hex(int('10000011101000011010100010010111', 2))
0x83a1a897
```

Or to get it in exactly the format you requested:

```
>>> '%08X' % int('10000011101000011010100010010111', 2)
83A1A897
```

Comment: Perfect, much better than my own solution!

Comment: "Perfect" [is best expressed as a green tick to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> binary = '10010111'
>>> int(binary,2)
151
>>> hex(int(binary,2))
'0x97'
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easy with build in functions.
The first thing you want to do is convert your binary to an integer:

```
>> int("1010",2)
10
```

The second step then would be to represent this as hex:

```
>> "%04X" % int("1010",2)
'000A'
```

in case you don't want any predefined length of the hex string then just use:

```
>> "%X" % int("1010",2)
'A'
>> "0x%X" % int("1010",2)
'0xA'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `hex(int("10", 2))` also works, but the main point is that you have to pass in a value for the second parameter for the int function. Its signature is `def __init__(self, x, base=10):`

Answer (score 0):

To read in a number in any base use the builtin `int` function with the optional second parameter specifying the base (in this case 2).

To convert a number to a string of its hexadecimal form just use the `hex` function.

```
>>> number=int("10000011101000011010100010010111",2)
>>> print hex(number)
0x83a1a897L
```

Answer (score 0):

Well we could string format just like Mark Byers said.Or in other way we could string format in another method like given below:

```
>>> print('{0:x}'.format(0b10000011101000011010100010010111))
83a1a897
```

To make the alphabets between the hex in upper case try this:

```
>>> print('{0:X}'.format(0b10000011101000011010100010010111))
83A1A897
```

Hope this is helpful.