# How to read binary data and display as a little endian hexstring in Python?

Tags: python

I want to read 4 byte of a binary file until it ends and want to display the result as a hex string e.g.

First 4 Bytes of my file are:

```
4D 5A 90 00
```

Result should be:

```
0x00905A4D
```

And I also want to be able to do different operations on the result for example:

```
result = 0x00905A4D
tmp = result & 0xFF
```

tmp should then be **0x4D**

What's the most elegant way for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python conversion from binary string to hexadecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072351/python-conversion-from-binary-string-to-hexadecimal)

Comment: Also, the syntax for hexadecimal literals is: `0x6789abcd`. So in your example you'd want to use `result = 0x00905a4d; tmp = result & 0xff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code does what you want:

```
from struct import unpack

inputFile = open("test.txt", "r")
byteString = inputFile.read(4)

# Unpack the first 4 bytes as a little ended unsigned integer
result = unpack("<I", byteString)[0]

# Do some bit arithmetic
tmp = result & 0xff

# Show variable values
print("%08x %08x" % (result, tmp))
```