# Python: How to convert a bitstring to its value in hex

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, byte, bit

How do you convert a bitstring (e.g. a string with only `0` and `1`) to its value in hex, using Python?

For example if I have the string `"1010110010010001"` its output in hex would be: `0xAC91`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python conversion from binary string to hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072351/python-conversion-from-binary-string-to-hexadecimal)

Answer (score 0):

Very easily:

```
>>> hex(int("1010110010010001", 2))
'0xac91'
```